# firebase.database is not a function node js

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try use firebase in nodejs. I install it with `npm install --save firebase`
After I try run this code

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
require("firebase/auth");
require("firebase/firestore");
require("firebase/database")
const source = require('./data');
let firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBAXdfdlw**********V4uPSCqGDEf2jXQ",
    authDomain: "wr-bot-*****.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://wr-bot-*****.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "wr-bot-*****",
    storageBucket: "wr-bot-*****.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "111*****9181",
    appId: "1:1116*****181:web:0729038*****f9d3fc2334"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = firebase.database();
```

And have this Error

```
const database = firebase.database();
                          ^

TypeError: firebase.database is not a function
```

I look here for answer, but nothing helped me

Comment: Since you tagged this "node.js", are you suggesting that you're trying to use the Firebase web SDK in a node program?

Answer (score 0):

You need to require firebase from firebase/app.